# Настройка платежной системы WebPay

Tags: php, динамические-массивы

Настраиваю платежную систему WebPay. Застрял на расчете общей суммы платежа. Вот код.

```
    if(count($data['products'])){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($data['products']); $i++){

                $fields["wsb_invoice_item_name[$i]"] = $data['products'][$i]['title'];
                $fields["wsb_invoice_item_quantity[$i]"] = "1";
                $fields["wsb_invoice_item_price[$i]"] = $data['products'][$i]['price'];

                $fields["wsb_total"] = $fields["wsb_invoice_item_quantity[$i]"] * 
$fields["wsb_invoice_item_price[$i]"];
```

Если значение wsb_total прописывать так:

```
    $fields["wsb_total"] = $fields["wsb_invoice_item_quantity[$i]"] * $fields["wsb_invoice_item_price[$i]"] + $fields["wsb_invoice_item_quantity[$i]"] * $fields["wsb_invoice_item_price[$i]"] + $fields["wsb_invoice_item_quantity[$i]"] * 
$fields["wsb_invoice_item_price[$i]"];
```

то все срабатывает корректно, при условии, что количество слагаемых соответствует количеству товаров в корзине. При чем для корректной работы системы расчет значения "wsb_total" должен быть именно по такой формуле. Но как сделать, чтобы эти слагаемые автоматически формировались и подставлялись? Подозреваю, что нужно формировать отдельный массив для поля $fields["wsb_total"], элементами которого являются такие слагаемые, а потом вычислять сумму этих элементов. Но как-то мозг не может зацепиться за правильный код. Как сформировать этот массив... Или я не в ту сторону подозреваю?

Comment: А где у вас подсчет суммы для всех товаров ? Вы ведь об этом в первую очередь спрашиваете как я понял.. В wsb_total  вы не сумму общую пишите, а каждый раз перезаписываете новое число (стоимость единицы * на количество). Или я не о том ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Вот работающий код:

```
    if(count($data['products'])){
        $sum = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($data['products']); $i++){

            $sum+= $data['products'][$i]['price'];

            $fields["wsb_invoice_item_name[$i]"] = $data['products'][$i]['title'];
            $fields["wsb_invoice_item_quantity[$i]"] = "1";
            $fields["wsb_invoice_item_price[$i]"] = $data['products'][$i]['price'];

            $fields["wsb_total"] = $sum;
```

Через переменную $sum. При чем этот способ попытался применить в самом начале. Но он не работал. И причину вижу в том, что сама по себе эта переменная объявляется в другой функции, которая выполняется в этом же коде, только выше. Соответственно данная функция очевидно не видела эту переменную. Когда я ввел ее отдельно для поля $fields["wsb_total"] внутри именно этой функции, все заработало.